# Scroll Sidebar with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a sidebar and content div. I want scroll page and height of content to be longer then my sidebar. Now I tried to fix my sidebar when height ended, but content scroll. My code is here:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding:5px 35px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="card d-none d-md-block" style="margin-top:30px;margin- 
          bottom:50px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 ">
            @include('Products.ProductList')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't use any classes for sidebar and content, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking for correctly, all you need to do is this and you can change that 500px height to whatever your max height needs to be:

```
.container-fluid {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```